# Why set on collection item returns pending promise

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Running this:

```
db.collection("test").doc()
                    .set({
                        value: 100
                    }).then(resultOrWhateverItReturns => { /*never executed*/ });
```

returns a promise always staying at its `pending` status, so the code in `then`  branch is never executed (I guess the same issue'd apply to `catch` one). I saw some [people](https://medium.com/@collardeau/es6-promises-with-firebase-76606f36c80c) wrapping `set` with another promise and resolving it right after `set` call, thus dealing with it pretty much as with a synchronous call, which doesn't look right.

Is there a way fire up insert/update commands returning useful i.e. fulfilled/rejected promises? I'm using v. `6.6.1` of sdk.

**Update 1** - Cloud Firestore documentation [suggests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) the following approach which doesn't work for me due to the fact that the promise returned by `set` is at pending state. The actual data does get updated alright.

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").set({
  name: "Frank",
  favorites: {
    food: "Pizza",
    color: "Blue",
    subject: "Recess"
  },
  age: 12
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Frank created");
});
```

Comment: "which doesn't work for me" What *does* this code do when you run it? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: "then" branch is never executed for me. Data gets added/updated but then part never called. Ideally I'd like to get the auto-generated id of the doc too.  + no need to be smart about language here buddy.

Comment: I'm not trying to be smart here, merely trying to help and it wasn't clear to me what wasn't working. Which SDK are you using? Client-side JavaScript in a browser? Or Node.js?

Comment: JS one v. 6.6.1 located by https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-firestore.js I updated the question, hope it made it cleared.

Comment: Do you have write permission to the collection? If not, your write will be rejected. If uncertain, add a `catch()` clause to your handler. `.catch(function(e) {
  console.error(e);
})`. Also see: https://jsbin.com/varegoc/2/edit?js,console

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks for putting up an example. Let me try it with my db. My code works in JsBin, must be my network security prevented Firebase just from reporing on the success.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use async- await ?
Eg:

```
 await db.collection('users').doc('frank').set({
         name: "Frank",
         favorites: {
         food: "Pizza",
         color: "Blue",
         subject: "Recess"
       },
       age: 12
 });
```

Have an async function like this:

```
const updateFn = async (userDetails) => {}
```

And call the collection update using await ?

Comment: It'll make no difference whatsoever, all await does it blocks execution until the promise is resolved, which never happens. The question I asked is why the promise returned by set always stays pending, please read it again.